# Runtime error due to @XmlJavaTypeAdapter not being resolved

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am using `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to generate Java classes from an XSD file. I have a bindings file with adapters for XML `date` elements that point to a fully qualified java class (e.g: `com.example.project.DateAdapter`).

When I run `mvn clean install` I see that the generated java classes in `./generated-sources/jaxb/` contain the correct import (full package name) for my adapters and the date fields are annotated with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, but when the classes are actually compiled to `./target/classes/` the `import` of the adapter does not have the fully qualified name and it appears as `import DateAdapter.java` instead of `import com.example.project.DateAdapter`. I noticed this after decompiling the .class file.

The issue I'm having is that when my application tries to run it fails because the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)` annotation cannot resolve the class, which makes sense because the import did not reference the fully qualifier name of the class.

I suspect that what is happening is that when Maven is compiling the generated java files classes it has no visibility on the .java files located under `./src/`. Could this be the issue?

Not sure if this helps but I'm using VSCode and  `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add the generated sources to the classpath.

Comment: Do you have complete steps to reproduce? Please show it or report it to the official developers on [GitHub](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new).